# Using mssql PreparedStatement in Node.js returning odd data

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, prepared-statement

I am working on using a PrepareStatement in Node to protect against SQL injections:

```
let conn = sql.connect(config[2], function (err) {

var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(conn);
  
let placeholders = {
    param: "*",
  };
  
  ps.input('param', sql.VarChar(20));

  let query = "SELECT @param FROM table"

  ps.prepare(query, (err1) => {

    ps.execute(placeholders, (err2, recordset) => {
      console.log(recordset.recordsets);

      ps.unprepare((err3) => {
        console.log('disconnected!');
      })
    })
});
```

When I run this I'm expecting the recordset to contain all of the data in 'table', but instead a list of {'': '*'} is returned, with a length equal to the number of rows in table.

If I replace the '@param' in query with a '*', then the correct data is returned, so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the PreparedStatement.

Note: I'm accessing an SQL server in Azure

Comment: you can't use placeholders for column names or table  names

Comment: Your query says "for every row of the table, return the value in the parameter". There is no injection of the parameter as actual code into the query, it remains a variable with string data in it, not code. To best prevent injection, and other errors, you should always have a static query that you *know* what it does and what columns it refers to, rather than using input from the user.